# Background script: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, content-script, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to send a message from background script to content script in my chrome extension. But it looks like the message gets send before the content script is loaded?

This is the error I get when I am using my extension normally:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

This is my background script with the `tabs.onUpdated` function:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {

    if (changeInfo.url) {
        console.log(changeInfo.url, tabId)
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            url: changeInfo.url,
            type: 'URL_CHANGE'
        });
    }
});
```

This is my content script receive function:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
    console.log('received', obj)
    if (obj.type === 'URL_CHANGE') {
        console.log('testestsetst')
        getAuth()
        getUrlType(obj.url)
    } else if (obj.type === 'AUTH') {
        getAuth()
    } else if (obj.type === 'UN-AUTH') {
        removeAuth()
    }
});
```

Whenever I run the extension normally I don't see an output from my content script and I get the error as stated above. However, when I debug the background script and step through the code, I get no error and my content script prints everything correctly. Could this be due to the page needing to load? And if so, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved it by checking for tab complete and sending the url through the tab parameter as follows:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
            url: tab.url,
            type: 'URL_CHANGE'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, saved the day!

Answer (score -1):

`background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    if (details.reason == "install") {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL(`onboard-page.html`) }, function (tab) {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changeInfo) {
                if (tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener)
                    // Now the tab is ready!
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "hello") 
                }
            });
        });
    } else if (details.reason == "update") {
        
    }
});
```

`content-script.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(message)
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer.